# Json response not coming in swift? but in postman response coming

Tags: json, swift

This is my working API: https://appleskool.com/preview/appleskool_code/api/register

and the request is:

```
 {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"params": {
    "fname":"tom",
    "lname":"test",
    "email":"tom@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345678",
    "phone_no":"0987654322",
    "device_type":"2",
"interest_skill":{
        "0":"23",
      "1":"27"
    }

 }
 }
```

for the above request i heve created model like below:

```
struct postdata: Codable{
var fname: String
var lname: String
var email: String
var password: String
var phone_no: String
var device_type: String
var interest_skill: [String : String]
}
struct params: Codable{
var params: postdata
}
```

and my code is:

```
func regService(){
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://appleskool.com/preview/appleskool_code/api/register")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   
    let jsonpost = params(params: postdata(fname: "tom", lname: "test", email: "tom@gmail.com", password: "12345678", phone_no: "0987654322", device_type: "2", interest_skill: ["0" : "23", "1" : "27"]))
        
    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonpost)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {
        print("Error while encoding parameter: \(error)")
    }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {return}
            
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]
                print("the json output \(json)")
            
            let namete = json!["fname"] as? String
            print("jhghgjk \(namete)")
            
        }catch{ print("Error while decoding: \(error)") }
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

in postman i am getting response but in my project response not coming but error also not showing, where am i wrong, pls do help
with the above code error not coming and response also not coming in simulator i got like below

> nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
> 2021-02-17 16:02:36.364930+0530 MachineTest[3184:286907] Connection 2: received failure notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're not building a proper request body, that's why server is not returning an expected answer. Where do you specify `jsonrpc` parameter in your code?

I suggest you make one more struct like:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
   var jsonrpc: String
   var params: PostData
}
```

And then use it when building a request:

```swift
let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(Response(/* To be somehow initialized */))
```